# How to change all elements of an array to specific value?

Tags: c++, arrays

For example I have an array like this:

```
bool log[100000]
```

And I have loop in which I want to set the value of all elements in log to True. In other words, I want to wipe all the changes what have been done to log after each cycle of the loop. How could I do it? Could I change not all but let's say 100 values?

Comment: You usually don't want to waste your stack with 100,000 `bool`s.

Comment: ok, where is the difficulty in this? even if not c++ way, you could write a for loop and do this?

Answer (score 5):

To fill the entire array with `true`:

```
std::fill(begin(log), end(log), true);
```

To fill the first 100 elements with `true`:

```
std::fill(begin(log), begin(log) + 100, true);
```

`begin` and `end` are added in C++11; if your compiler and library don't support them, consider using `std::array<bool, N>` instead, which has `begin` and `end` member functions.  You really should use the `std::array` template anyway, since it has no overhead, provides the standard sequence container interface, and helps  you to avoid the silly semantics of C arrays.

Comment: Or, consider `std::vector<bool>`, which reduces the memory footprint by 87%.

Comment: @Rob:  One should consider `std::vector<char>` for this case.  The non-container container `std::vector<bool>` should be avoided.

Comment: @Rob: how does `std::vector` reduce memory footprint.. any pointers? thanks.

Comment: @JamesMcNellis: What is a 'non-container container'?

Comment: @Lazer:  The horrible `std::vector<bool>` stores its elements in a compressed form, as an array of bits, so it consumes roughly 1/8 the amount of memory as a `std::vector<char>` of the same size.  However, this compressed storage form means that it's not a real container since its elements cannot be addressed individually.  This has lots of implications, including potentially worse performance, depending on how it is used.

Comment: Or potentially better performance, depending upon how it is used. For example, filling a 100K-element vector (http://ideone.com/eY2lH) reveals a 16:1 increase in perforance by using `vector<bool>` instead of `vector<char>`.